# Using TeamCity to build C# 6 application on outdated Windows Server 2008 (NOT R2)

Tags: c#, msbuild, mono, teamcity, windows-server-2008

We are using that version on Amazon. I'm not sure if there is any good solution to upgrade Windows without reinstalling everything.

Looks like it's not possible to install Microsoft Build Tools 2015 on that Windows version. Can it be "hacked"? This is not a production server so I don't care if it would be not fully secure.

Another workaround I think could be using mono. I installed the latest mono version but build agent doesn't detect it. How to fix it? Will it work if I'm going to run that mono-compiled app on MS .NET? Can mono compiler handle mixed-mode assembly references (we don't need to compile them, just use)?

Or can you suggest anything another?

Comment: What version of TeamCity are you running? Could you create a new Amazon VM instance with a newer OS and just install an agent on it and have the build server run the build on that agent?

Comment: @Nanhydrin, TeamCity 8.1.4 (build 30168). No, I can't install it another machine because we use it not only for build but also for dev deployment (binary files are copied where they should be, some services are restarted, etc). It would take too much effort to configure everything we need for dev server again.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but my serious recommendation would be to take the pain of upgrading to Server 2012, TeamCity 9.1 now. You're just going to keep coming up against this problem with new tech. One way or another you'll probably need to upgrade to TeamCity 9.1 to get support for the 2015 build tools. You're ideally situated to do this since it's running on Amazon, you can just spin up a new VM and get things working on that without killing your old VM until the new one is stable. Sorry that's not an answer but I've been there and it's just storing up pain for the future.